# rspec to have changed by 1, but was changed by 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have following code to test action create of controller

```
    let(:custom_action)     { create :custom_action, entity: entity }

Describe '#create' do  
        context 'with valid attributes' do
          before { allow(controller).to receive(:custom_actions_path).and_return('/') }

          subject { post :create, params: { custom_action: {
            name: custom_action.name,
            label: custom_action.label,
            url: custom_action.url,
            request_method: custom_action.request_method,
            entity_id: entity.id
          }, 
            locale: user.language }}

          it 'should increment resource list by 1' do 
            expect { subject }.to change { CustomAction.count }.by(1)
          end
       end
    end
```

When i running test  i get: **To have changed by 1, but was changed by 2**

I checked action, if create new object always create one, not two.

Have I correct used **subject**? What wrong with my test? Thank you

Comment: Have you used `let` to define your `custom_action`?

Comment: yes. i updated question with code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `subject` within your `expect` block evaluates the `subject` block. Subject block calls your action, but it needs to evaluate `custom_action` to do so. In the end, while evaluating the block, your `custom_action` block creates one `CustomAction` and your actual, controller action creates one more during the request.

Change your `let` to `let!` to fix your test.

Comment: @StefanHansch `let!` makes your `custom_action` block be executed immediately when declared. This mean that it will immediately create one `CustomAction`, not only when actually used within your `subject`.